# highcharts dynamic line chart from json

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a chart that needs to pull data from a json presented by a servlet.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/dcSUq/

as you can see its not loading the data correctly.  Do I need to build the name: and data: field directly?

I'm using:

```
var chart1 = {...}; // see jsfiddle link above

var cData = [];
var d = chart1.data;
for (var i in d) {
    var x = new Array(d[i].city, d[i].pph);
    cData.push(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to build the data into the correct format before it will work.
eg

```
series: [{
name: 'Tokyo',
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}, {
name: 'New York',
data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
}, {
name: 'Berlin',
data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
}, {
name: 'London',
data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
}]
```

Comment: I know what the highcharts series looks like -but how do I convert my JSON data into an array that will be accepted by highcharts as a viable data series?

Answer (score 0):

ok - took me a 30 min review on building arrays in javascript but here's my duh code:

```
var cData = [];
var d = chart1.data;
for (var i in d) {
    var x = new Array();
    x['name'] = d[i].city;
    x['data'] = d[i].pph;
    cData.push(x);
}
```

updated my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/dcSUq/